# Storing TCP session object on a distributed cache (Redis)

Tags: java, session, caching, tcp, redis

I am having a requirement where 
1. I have two TCP servers which needs to be made high available.
2. There will be communication from the client (a Device) to TCP server (Apache Mina) and from server back to the client.
3. Once the TCP connection is established between the server and the client I need to store the session object in a distributed cache (Redis) so that in case of failure of on Machine the other machine can pick up session object from the Redis cache and connect with the client.

Has anyone tried storing Apache mina TCP IoSession object on a Redis cache. When I attempted I got the following error.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type com.iot.device.server.DeviceRequestHandler at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.serializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:144)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:820)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:429)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

Following is the snippet which I used to store the IoSession Object on redis.

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "sessionCache", key = "T(io.device.redis.service.ControlledCacheService).getSessionCacheKey(#relevant)")
    public IoSession populateSessionCache(String relevant, IoSession value) {
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: You can't just magically migrate a TCP connection between machines by saving a high-level language wrapper object in Redis.

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart for the quick response. Is there any options or solutions that you can suggest for this scenario.

Comment: @ARUNKUMAR facing same issue i want to store IoT device TCP connection using Redis you find any solution for this issue ?